# iOS9 Dev Stanford Calculator display disappeared when landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm new to iOS dev and I'm following the Stanford iOS9 course in iTunes U.

And I was very confused when the UILabel display disappeared when I rotate the device to landscape:

[image]

iPhone 5s simulator. Also doesn't show up on my iPod touch (iOS 9.3)

But it seems to be fine on iPhone 6 or iPad simulators

And here's my storyboard:

[image]

My Xcode version is 7.3.1

Does anyone know the reason? 
THANKS!

------------------Update  Jun 1--------------------

I tried to change the property “Distribution" of the stack view, which contains the display and the panel, from "fill" to "fill proportionally", and the display showed up!

When I tried to use view debugging, I found that the display became a line. But I still can't find mistakes. All constraints seem to be correct.

Code:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var display: UILabel!

    private var userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping=false
    private var userTypedDecimalPoint=false

    @IBAction private func touchDigit(sender: UIButton) {
        let digit=sender.currentTitle!


        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping && display.text != "0" {
            if userTypedDecimalPoint && (digit == "."){

            } else {
                let textCurrentlyInDisplay = display.text!
                display.text = textCurrentlyInDisplay + digit
                if digit == "." {
                    userTypedDecimalPoint = true
                }
            }
        } else {
            if digit == "." {
                display.text = "0."
                userTypedDecimalPoint = true
            } else if (digit == "0") && (display.text == "0") {
                // Do nothing...
            } else {
                display.text = digit
            }
        }
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = true
    }

    private var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            return Double(display.text!)!
        }
        set {
            display.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }

    private var brain = CalculatorBrain()

    @IBAction private func performOperation(sender: UIButton) {
        if userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping {
            brain.setOperand(displayValue)
            userIsInTheMiddleOfTyping = false
        }
        userTypedDecimalPoint = false
        if let mathmaticalSymbol = sender.currentTitle {
            brain.performOperation(mathmaticalSymbol)
        }
        displayValue = brain.result
    }
}
```

And I didn't modify the file AppDelegate.swift

Comment: Please post relevant code and context

Comment: My first guess would be layout constraints.  However, the way to debug it, I think, would be to use Xcode's view debugging feature.  It will let you see whether there's something blocking your label or whether it may be off-screen.

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks for your advice and I found that the display became a single line!  And the constraints seem to be fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Distribution = "Fill Proportionally" for the topmost Stack View. It may help/